# Rails returning GET response as HTML, not redirecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Running the following code shows that the Controller and the View are receiving and parsing the JSON appropriately, and returning HTML. (This can be seen through the alert in the call back function.)

However, what I want is for the browser to be redirected to /json_test/main, not to just receive the HTML in response.

Controller:

```
class JsonTestController < ApplicationController
  def main
    @postData = params[:scores]
  end
  def test
  end
end
```

main.html.erb:

```
<h1>JsonTest#main</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/json_test/main.html.erb</p>

<% @postData.each do |key, value| %>
    <p><%= key %> : <%= value %></p>
<% end %>
```

test.html.erb:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var postUrl = "<%= json_test_main_path %>";
var postJson = JSON.parse('{ "scores" : { "player1": 5, "player2": 6 } }');

 $.get(postUrl, postJson, function(data, status, xhr) {
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
}, "html");

</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you expect a redirect to happen? There's nothing in your code

Comment: I thought the default was to render the View specified in the URL ( in this case /json_test/main)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the point of doing an AJAX request if your goal is to redirect the user unto another page?

There is no point.

Nonetheless, you can add a success callback in your $.get which redirects the browser.

```
  .done(function() {
    window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
  })
```

Comment: How would I redirect to this page with the necessary parameters without using a GET request? (I apologize if this is a dumb question.)

Comment: Your AJAX request is the $.GET. Without some kind of request, there's no AJAX action. I think you are not sure of what you want yet.